# QuickSort not sorting properly

Tags: c, sorting

I have a this program to receive a struct, store it and then sort it. I have tried to use Shell Sort, but then I went for the Quick Sort Algorithm. However, when I try to print the array after sorting, it still returns it unsorted. Bear in mind im trying to sort it by 'num_aluno'.

**CODE**

```
typedef struct ALUNO
{
char primeiro_nome[15];
char segundo_nome[15];
int num_aluno;
float nota;

}ALUNO;

void swap(ALUNO* a, ALUNO* b)
{
ALUNO t=*a;
*a=*b;
*b=t;
}
int partition(ALUNO *studentList, int low, int high)
{
int pivot= studentList[high].num_aluno;
int i=(low-1);
int j;

for(j=low;j<=high-1;j++)
{
    if(studentList[j].num_aluno<=pivot);
    {
        i++;
        swap(&studentList[i], &studentList[j]);
    }
}
swap(&studentList[i+1], &studentList[high]);
return(i+1);
}
void quickSort(ALUNO *studentList, int low, int high)
{
if(low<high)
{
    int pi=partition(studentList, low, high);

    quickSort(studentList, low, pi-1);
    quickSort(studentList, pi+1, high);
}
}

int main()
{
ALUNO *studentList=NULL;
int currentPos, studentListSize=1;
//float grade_sum=0;

studentList=(ALUNO*)calloc(studentList, studentListSize*sizeof(ALUNO));

printf("Insira o numero de alunos \n");
scanf("%d", &studentListSize);

studentList=(ALUNO*)realloc(studentList, studentListSize*sizeof(ALUNO));

for(currentPos=0;currentPos<studentListSize;currentPos++)
{
    newStudent(studentList, currentPos);
}

quickSort(studentList, 0, studentListSize);

for(currentPos=0;currentPos<studentListSize;currentPos++)
{
    printStudent(studentList,currentPos);
}

free(studentList);

return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Take a debugger and debug your code.

Comment: First get the surrounding of your sorting right, using a simple sorting algo, like bubble sort. This is practically the recommendatin from here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: Already did, doesn't give me any error

Comment: `studentList=(ALUNO*)calloc(studentList, studentListSize*sizeof(ALUNO));` that's wrong! (but that's not the cause of the error)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, really? Why is it wrong?

Comment: `calloc` takes 2 parameters: the number of elements, and the size. you're passing a null pointer as the first element. Doesn't matter, though since you're reallocating properly from null pointer afterwards. Just remove that line.

Comment: maybe you could check other (working) quicksort c implementations. There are a lot of them out there.

Comment: which would also help would be a [mcve] with all input data inside, so others can try to compile & run & fix your code. Currently there are missing functions & inputs.

Comment: I would use C's standard quicksort implementation, but the assignment requires me to code it. Thanks anyway

Comment: the assignment doesn't prevent you from looking at some working source to understand your error

Comment: Your `partition()` function and therefore your `quickSort()` function assume that their `high` parameter designates the largest index in the (sub-)array, but at the initial call to `quickSort()` you pass the size of the array, which is one greater than the maximum index.

Comment: What do you mean by "*doesn't give me any error*"? Do you not know how to debug code?

Comment: Review `calloc(studentList, studentListSize*sizeof(ALUNO));` ---> `studentList = realloc(studentListSize, sizeof *studentList);`

Comment: @Sombrito: What all of these comments are trying to tell you is that this code requires further effort on your part. You need to step through it in a debugger and find out what's not happening like you think it should. You can't just post your code and say "I wrote this and it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?". Stack Overflow is not a homework-writing service.

Comment: I suggest turning on maximum warnings in your compiler.  With `gcc`, that would be approximately `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.  With that combination, the main problem pops right out as a warning (though it seems in this case `-Wextra` is the particular needful option).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't sort the list is, i and j are always the same value in the partition function.

You should start j from high -1, not from low.
Also, you are not considering the values of studentList[i]. You must guarantee that it is larger than pivot, otherwise there may be a value which is smaller than the pivot, yet at the left part of the array.

Here, corrected it.

```
    int partition(ALUNO*studentList, int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = studentList[high].num_aluno;
    int i=low ;
    int j;

    for(j=high-1;j>=i;)
    {
        while(studentList[i].num_aluno < pivot)
         i++;
        while(studentList[j].num_aluno > pivot)
         j--;


            if(i<=j){
            swap(&studentList[i], &studentList[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
            }


    }
    swap(&studentList[i], &studentList[high]);
    return(i+1);
}
```

An additional advice in case you have not heard of it, do not choose the first or last values as pivots. Instead, use the median of three strategy.

Median of three strategy: Pick the first, middle and last elements in the unsorted array. Change their locations according to their values in a sorted manner. Then take the middle value and use it as a pivot. This way you are avoiding the worst time complexity(O(n^2)) of QuickSort.